# Laravel - não grava preço quando valor é NULL

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um mutator do Laravel para tratar um campo, porém se o campo vem vazio ele não salva de jeito nenhum no banco o valor predefinido.

**MODEL**

```
/// PROMOÇÃO TROCA VIRGULA POR PONTO
public function setPromocaoAttribute($value)
{
    $value==null ? '0.00' : $this->attributes['promocao'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value);
}
```

nem predefinindo antes nem mesmo no banco funciona

no banco está OBS:(também já tentei deixar NULL no banco, mesmo assim não atualiza o campo)

> 'promocao'    decimal(8,2) NOT-NULL e também Default ('0.00')

Precisava que fique salvo como null, ou como 0.00 mas ta difícil kkk
aparentemente só quer salvar se o valor for maior que 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está retornando o valor `'0.00'` para lugar nenhum e, quando a entrava for nula, o campo não é modificado.

Ao invés de

```
public function setPromocaoAttribute($value)
{
    $value==null ? '0.00' : $this->attributes['promocao'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value);
}
```

Faça

```
public function setPromocaoAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['promocao'] = ($value == null) ? '0.00' :  str_replace(",", ".", $value);
}
```

Assim, o atributo `promocao` irá receber `'0.00'` se `$value` for nulo.

Ou ainda, se utilizar o PHP 7, pode utilizar o operador `??`:

```
$this->attributes['promocao'] = str_replace(",", ".", $value ?? '0.00');
```

Comment: Show de bola mano! funcionou perfeitamente,  sim é php 7. Obrigado.